# Ubuntu Server won't boot GBT

Tags: boot, server, grub2, mbr

I have an hp proliant ml10 v2 server.

The USB ubuntu install only works with ubuntu 18 as 20.4 and 20.10 goes black screen after grub menu.

After installing ubuntu 18 the system says non system disk.

I've seen solutions of changing gpt to MBR but without a working Linux box it's difficult as most solutions are using Linux cli.

I wish ubuntu would give the option to setup boot disk to work with older machines.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to install the desktop or the server version of Ubuntu? You may need to boot from the live USB using the UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

I am an "newbie", but will share what I know. Last week, I installed Ubuntu 20.24 (the desktop/Server package) on my ASUS Sabertooth, R2.0 motherboard, running an eight core AMD chip at 3.8 G-Htz, with 8 gig of ram, having a WD 2.0 T-bite HD. It would not boot up to the start up screen. During installation, the internet connection was severed. I determined that was the cause. Installation would hang, giving a[WARNING]... After asking some questions, and looking over answers, using this forum and answers from internet searches to accomplish the updates, I opened the  terminal and installed updates for all my apps, which I chose during setup. Finally, after some frustration, the updates were installed, but it still would not boot up, even though it did boot further than where it was prior to the updates/up-grades. Afterwards, I found one suggestion suggested to disconnect all exterior drives. After I removed my CD/DVD drive, it did boot up completely for me. Part of the process included booting up again, with my installation flash drive inserted. I believe this gave the boot process access to information it needed to correct the problems made by the interrupted network during the first installation. At any rate, my server boots up now. I am able to access the desktop area with my password, although I am still in the process of completing my server set up.